# Using a switch statement with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I am attempting to use a switch statement to check if a child has a class. If this child has a particular class, it will add/remove a class to/from that child. The jQuery code I have right now is this:

```
jQuery(".navigation .navmenu .navbox").mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass("activenavbox");

    switch(jQuery(this).children("a")){
        case jQuery(this).hasClass("homebg"):
            jQuery(this).addClass("homeiconhover");
            jQuery(this).removeClass("homebg");
        }
});


jQuery(".navigation .navmenu .navbox").mouseleave(function(){
     jQuery(this).removeClass("activenavbox");
         switch(this){
            case(this).children("a").hasClass("homeiconhover"):
              jQuery(this).children("a").removeClass("homeiconhover");
              jQuery(this).children("a").addClass("homebg");
          }
});
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul class="navmenu" style="display: inline-block; list-style-type: none;">
        <li class="navbox"><a class="navlink homebg" href="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navbox"><a class="navlink aboutbg" href="/about">About</a>       </li>
        <li class="navbox"><a class="navlink projectsbg" href="/projects">Our Projects</a></li>
        <li class="navbox"><a class="navlink contactbg" href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="navbox"><a class="navlink loginbg" href="/login">Client Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case, an `if` statement or a `toggleClass()` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I don't quite understand the flow here.  I think there are some scenarios where both would fail, and no classes would change.

Comment: jamen, if you are referring to me, you are correct... this was a simple paste to show what i am envisioning... i think toggleclass/if may work, i need to check it out more. was just hoping for some suggestions on the problem, not have folks solve it for me.

Answer (score 1):

A `switch` statement will compare `case` values to the result of the passed expression. Here, you are comparing a jQuery Object with a boolean. The case will never be reached unless the jQuery Object returns a boolean.

Instead, you could use jQuery selectors to do that check for you, along with the 
[`jQuery( selector, context )`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) function:

```
jQuery(".navigation .navmenu .navbox").mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass("activenavbox");

    jQuery("a.homebg", this).addClass("homeiconhover").removeClass("homebg");
});


jQuery(".navigation .navmenu .navbox").mouseleave(function(){
     jQuery(this).removeClass("activenavbox");

     jQuery("a.homeiconhover", this).removeClass("homeiconhover").addClass("homebg");
});
```

or do it like this:

```
jQuery(".navigation .navmenu .navbox").mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass("activenavbox")
                .children("a.homebg")
                .addClass("homeiconhover")
                .removeClass("homebg");
});


jQuery(".navigation .navmenu .navbox").mouseleave(function(){
     jQuery(this).removeClass("activenavbox");
                 .children("a.homeiconhover")
                 .removeClass("homeiconhover")
                 .addClass("homebg");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be written like that:

```
switch($(this).children("a").hasClass("homeiconhover")){
   case true:
       jQuery(this).children("a").removeClass("homeiconhover");
       jQuery(this).children("a").addClass("homebg");
}
```